# Error when connecting to vpn using NEVPNManager in iOS

Tags: ios, vpn, nevpnmanager

I am trying to configure vpn programatically using NEVPNManager and i was successful upto saving the preferences , but i am getting error **"negotiation with the VPN server failed"**  when i try to connect. Is there anything to do specific in protocolConfiguration to make it working??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your are setting the VPN config properly.
Here is the sample code.

NEVPNProtocolIPSec *protocalConfigurationIPSec = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
           protocalConfigurationIPSec.username = @"account";

```
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.passwordReference = passwordReference;
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.serverAddress = @"ipaddress";
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.sharedSecretReference = sharedSecretReference;
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.localIdentifier = @"userGroup"];
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.remoteIdentifier = [serverDict objectForKey:@"userGroup";
        **protocalConfigurationIPSec.useExtendedAuthentication = YES;**
        protocalConfigurationIPSec.disconnectOnSleep = NO;
        manager.protocolConfiguration=protocalConfigurationIPSec;
        [manager setOnDemandEnabled:NO];
        [manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VPN"];
        manager.enabled = true;
```

Comment: thank you murali. I error was happened with the local and remote identifiers.